# Excel 2013 x64 Активировать книгу, созданную из формы

Tags: excel, vba, x86-64

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Создаём пустую форму с кнопкой и кодом на клик кнопки

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Unload Me

With ThisWorkbook
   .Worksheets.Add
   Set ws = .ActiveSheet
   ws.Move
End With
Set ws = Nothing
```

Далее на лист добавляем кнопку из раздела "Элемент управления формы", которая показывает эту форму.

Проблема в том, что созданная макросом книга как-то не до конца активируется (при попытке печати почему-то печатается изначальная книга). Наблюдается в Excel 2013 x64. В более ранних версиях такого точно нет.

Как это можно победить? Активация новой книги происходит, если ручками сначала переключиться на старую книгу, затем опять перейти на новую, но эта же операция через код эффекта не даёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решения данной проблемы так и не нашёл. Есть обходной путь - вместо элемента управления формы использовать элементы ActiveX. С ними такой проблемы не возникает.